# Converting an api output to dictionary format

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary

I am working on an app that takes in Schedule of movies airing across different channels in my country as an Api output . The problem is I can't make heads or tails of the output provided by the developer . He hasn't provided any documentation and example output result.

```
output = 00:00:00 :- MN+ HD : Gone Girl (Ben Affleck, Rosamund Pike, Neil Patrick Harris, Tyler Perry, Carrie Coon, Kim Dickens, Patrick Fugit, Missi Pyle, Casey Wilson, Sela Ward, David Clennon, Leonard Kelly Young, Darin Cooper) 
00:00:00 :- MNX : Double Impact (Jean Claude Damme, Geoffrey Lewis, Alan Scarfe, Bolo Yeung, Alonna Shaw, Alicia Stevenson, Peter Malota)
```

I want to convert this into a nested list of lists with each list containing a dictionary with key/value pairs being Showtime , Channel name , Movie name and cast .

Thank you

Comment: That can't be the actual API call. Are you going through log files?

Comment: Looks like you can split on the closing `)` to get movies then on `:` and `(` to get time, channel, name, and cast.  Give it a try and if you get stuck post your code and people are sure to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's your question? Like, what have you tried, and where are you stuck? Are you aware of regex, or maybe just `str.split()`? Check out [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` module for the task:

```py
import re

output = '''\
00:00:00 :- MN+ HD : Gone Girl (Ben Affleck, Rosamund Pike, Neil Patrick Harris, Tyler Perry, Carrie Coon, Kim Dickens, Patrick Fugit, Missi Pyle, Casey Wilson, Sela Ward, David Clennon, Leonard Kelly Young, Darin Cooper)
00:00:00 :- MNX : Double Impact (Jean Claude Damme, Geoffrey Lewis, Alan Scarfe, Bolo Yeung, Alonna Shaw, Alicia Stevenson, Peter Malota)'''

for a, b, c in re.findall(r':-\s*(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*?)\)', output):
    print(f'channel name: {a}')
    print(f'movie name: {b}')
    cast = [n.strip() for n in c.split(',')]
    print(f'cast: {cast}')
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
channel name: MN+ HD
movie name: Gone Girl
cast: ['Ben Affleck', 'Rosamund Pike', 'Neil Patrick Harris', 'Tyler Perry', 'Carrie Coon', 'Kim Dickens', 'Patrick Fugit', 'Missi Pyle', 'Casey Wilson', 'Sela Ward', 'David Clennon', 'Leonard Kelly Young', 'Darin Cooper']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
channel name: MNX
movie name: Double Impact
cast: ['Jean Claude Damme', 'Geoffrey Lewis', 'Alan Scarfe', 'Bolo Yeung', 'Alonna Shaw', 'Alicia Stevenson', 'Peter Malota']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

A list of dictionaries as an output:

```
import re

output = """\
00:00:00 :- MN+ HD : Gone Girl (Ben Affleck, Rosamund Pike, Neil Patrick Harris, Tyler Perry, Carrie Coon, Kim Dickens, Patrick Fugit, Missi Pyle, Casey Wilson, Sela Ward, David Clennon, Leonard Kelly Young, Darin Cooper)
00:00:00 :- MNX : Double Impact (Jean Claude Damme, Geoffrey Lewis, Alan Scarfe, Bolo Yeung, Alonna Shaw, Alicia Stevenson, Peter Malota)"""

out = []
for showtime, a, b, c in re.findall(
    r"^(.*?)\s*:-\s*(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*?)\)", output, flags=re.M
):
    cast = [n.strip() for n in c.split(",")]
    out.append({"Channel Name": a, "Movie Name": b, "Cast": cast, "Showtime": showtime})

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "Channel Name": "MN+ HD",
        "Movie Name": "Gone Girl",
        "Cast": [
            "Ben Affleck",
            "Rosamund Pike",
            "Neil Patrick Harris",
            "Tyler Perry",
            "Carrie Coon",
            "Kim Dickens",
            "Patrick Fugit",
            "Missi Pyle",
            "Casey Wilson",
            "Sela Ward",
            "David Clennon",
            "Leonard Kelly Young",
            "Darin Cooper",
        ],
        "Showtime": "00:00:00",
    },
    {
        "Channel Name": "MNX",
        "Movie Name": "Double Impact",
        "Cast": [
            "Jean Claude Damme",
            "Geoffrey Lewis",
            "Alan Scarfe",
            "Bolo Yeung",
            "Alonna Shaw",
            "Alicia Stevenson",
            "Peter Malota",
        ],
        "Showtime": "00:00:00",
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej . Suppose I need to add showtimings to the list , I just need to another variable here for a, b, c in re.findall(r":-\s*(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*?)\)", output): ?

Comment: thank you so much . I was stuck on it for 2 days .

Comment: Hello Andrej , sorry to disturb you again . But the actual format I'm working is                                      00:00:00   :- And Pictures : The Killer (Irrfan Khan, Emraan Hashmi, Nisha Kothari, Bharati Achrekar, Zakir Hussain, Avtar Gill, Sanjay Batra, Prithvi Zutshi)<br>00:00:00   :- And Pictures HD : Boyz 2 Men (Siddharth, Genelia D'souza, Bharath, S Thaman, Manikandan, Nakul)<br> is like this , there is a <br> between the two movies not a gap . When I tried your code it was only giving the first value . Is there a way around it ?

Comment: @KARTIKBISHT Try to use `str.replace` to replace `<br>` with newline `\n` first.